# Using stopwatch in a console application

Tags: c#, timespan, stopwatch

I want to make a simple stopwatch in C# console. When you press S key you start the stopwatch and Q key to stop the stopwatch. And at the end the elapsed time will show in Hours:Min:Sec. Until now the stopwatch starts but when it stops it doesnt get the elapsed time.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Console.WriteLine("The stopwatch, press S to begin and Q to stop");
    var UserInput = Console.ReadLine();
    System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch stopWatch = new System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch();
    stopWatch.Start();

    switch (UserInput)
    {
        case "s":
            stopWatch.Start();;
            break;
        case "q":
            stopWatch.Stop();

            break;
        default:
            Console.WriteLine("You did something wrong");
            break;
    }

    // Get the elapsed time as a TimeSpan value.
    TimeSpan ts = stopWatch.Elapsed;

    // Format and display the TimeSpan value. 
    string elapsedTime = String.Format("{0:00}:{1:00}:{2:00}.{3:00}",
        ts.Hours, ts.Minutes, ts.Seconds,
        ts.Milliseconds / 2);
    Console.WriteLine("RunTime " + elapsedTime);

    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

This is the output:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/VKtCQ.png

Comment: What is your output exactly?

Comment: Why does your stopwatch start before you handle the pressed key?

Comment: Are you typing 'Q' to stop, or 'q'?

Comment: There's nothing wrong with the Stopwatch class. Why do you say it doesn't work? What did you do, what did you expect and what happened? Most likely there's *another* problem involved

Comment: `Stopwatch` is *very* simple. It doesn't "run" anything. It stores the value of the high performance tick counter when it starts. When you call `Stop` it retrieves the current counter value and compares it to the original to calculate `Elapsed`. When you call `Elapsed` while it's still running, it compares the current vs original counter value. If you get an unexpected value it probably means there's a problem in the code.

Comment: Also you should loop the application while the stopwatch is running and only output the elapsed time after you have pressed `q`

Comment: @marsze no, [it behaves differently](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#system/services/monitoring/system/diagnosticts/Stopwatch.cs,150) based on whether it's "running" or not

Comment: @marsze that's not what the source shows.

Comment: @marsze that's not what the source does at all. `elapsed` is the stored value. That's the default return value, set by `Stop(). Not the current one. ONLY if running, is the current one returned, without updating anything. The current value is returned *only* if Stopwatch is "running"

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Not `elapsed` is increased but `timeElapsed`. Anyways, I think we both know how it works, but fail to understand each other. In a nutshell: `Elapsed` (the property) returns the current elapsed time when running, and stays constant when stopped. That's what you meant too, right?

Comment: @Eldy I updated the post with a pictuer.

Comment: @Aars93 I just wanted to see if it works my bad

Comment: @kjhf the 'q' key not 'Q'

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos you are right it does work, but I wanted the elapsed time to show. It's true that timeElapsed is increased and I found it weird why it didnt write in the console. And thank you for clarefying.

Comment: @marsze Thank you :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're missing a loop. You probably press 's' to start and when you press 'q' you're actually hitting the last Console.ReadLine()

If you add a loop, everything works:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("The stopwatch, press S to begin and Q to stop");
        System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch stopWatch = new System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch();
        stopWatch.Start();

        var done = false;

        while (!done)
        {
            var UserInput = Console.ReadLine();

            switch (UserInput)
            {
                case "s":
                    stopWatch.Start();
                    break;
                case "q":
                    stopWatch.Stop();
                    done = true;
                    break;
                default:
                    Console.WriteLine("You did something wrong");
                    break;
            }
        }

        // Get the elapsed time as a TimeSpan value.
        TimeSpan ts = stopWatch.Elapsed;

        // Format and display the TimeSpan value. 
        string elapsedTime = String.Format("{0:00}:{1:00}:{2:00}.{3:00}",
            ts.Hours, ts.Minutes, ts.Seconds,
            ts.Milliseconds / 2);
        Console.WriteLine("RunTime " + elapsedTime);

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 2):

This reeks of homework, but:

Your major issue is not that your code won't "work", it's that you're flying straight through the whole stopwatch part of the code. You've got no loop to get hold of the user input repeatedly, so essentially it doesn't matter what input your user has in the first place. Try it, put a sleep in after your switch statement for a second `System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000)` and then put in various user inputs.

I recommend you look into `do while` loops to get your user input to be repeatedly accepted. In principle every section of your code would probably work if you can figure out how to cycle the input.

P.S. I can't see why you're dividing your Milliseconds by 2. That's going to cause you a headache later on.

Answer (score -1):

You can do something like this:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("The stopwatch, press S to begin and Q to stop");
        var UserInput = Console.ReadLine();
        System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch stopWatch = new System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch();
        stopWatch.Start();


    Decide:
        switch (UserInput.ToLower())
        {
            case "s":
                stopWatch.Start();

                while (!Console.KeyAvailable)
                {
                    // Get the elapsed time as a TimeSpan value.
                    TimeSpan ts = stopWatch.Elapsed;
                    Console.Clear();
                    // Format and display the TimeSpan value. 
                    string elapsedTime = String.Format("{0:00}:{1:00}:{2:00}.{3:00}",
                        ts.Hours, ts.Minutes, ts.Seconds,
                        ts.Milliseconds / 2);
                    Console.WriteLine("RunTime " + elapsedTime);
                    Thread.Sleep(1000);
                }

                UserInput = Console.ReadLine();
                if (UserInput.ToLower() != "q")
                {
                    goto Decide;
                }
                break;
            case "q":
                stopWatch.Stop();

                break;
            default:
                Console.WriteLine("You did something wrong");
                break;
        }
    }
```

Comment: What does your code do, and why do you think this helps the OP?

Comment: the OP wants to stop the stopwatch on press of the key and this solves the problem

Comment: Is it really necessary to use `goto` ?

Comment: according to me the code looks more readable than using another while loop

Comment: @UweKeim, Nitin Sawant is right that is what I want very simple but I screwed up. Thanks Nitin, But I wont use goto.